# Как отличить нажатие на кнопку кастомной клавиатуры в Telegram от обычного ввода текста?

Tags: api, telegram-bot, бот

Добрый день.
Подскажите можно как-то отличить нажатие на кнопку кастомной клавиатуры в Telegram от обычного ввода текста? Т.е. для пользователя формируется клавиатура и нужно знать что он нажал на кнопку этой клавиатуры а не ввел этот текст с помощью обычной клавиатуры.